# Different Import Locations per Camera in Lightroom 3

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-3, import

I've got various cameras that i use for different things.  For the purpose of organization I historically keep them in individual folders by camera.  I am trying to switch to using Lightroom to import the pictures for me (I current just copy/paste the files in Windows Explorer).  I see that I can choose an import location for my imported photos to go, but I don't see any way to change it by camera.  Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for?  Or is it time to break this old tradition and just let Lightroom do it's own thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply create a different [import preset](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Lightroom/3.0/Using/WS43660fa5a9ec95a81172e08124c124bb67-8000.html) for each camera, and customize the import location and metadata settings for each.

This is also very useful if you have multiple photographers (husband and wife for instance) sharing a catalog.

Comment: That's a good option - that link was a little light on the details, but I finally found where it is (at the very bottom of the screen in the import area of Lightroom).  We're getting closer.  But while that is still just 1 setting change, it's actually almost equally easy to change the destination directory, as the 2 sit right next to each other.  My ideal scenario is to plug the camera in, Lightroom launches and imports the pictures to the proper directory for me.  Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Looks like this is the best I can do for now!  :)